# How to output special characters in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, special-characters

I'm programming a basic MapReduce program where the input file is plain text, basically the program counts how many times a word appears in the input, and has to output another plain text file that looks like this:

> firstword 4
>
> secondword 10
>
> thirdword 2

etc, where (number)word is a word that appears in the input and the number besides it is how many times it appears in the file.

I have the code and it is working, but if my input text file has special characters (á, é, ì, ö, û, ñ, etc) the output file will display like this:

(if the first word is, for example, fábrica, and it appears 6 times):

> fã¡brica 6

how can I fix this issue? thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. If you're using the standard Python 3 tools and UTF-8 encoding for everything, you shouldn't have problems like this ([mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)). You need to make a [mre] of the problem and [edit] to add it to the question.

Comment: The key is that your code writes to the file using the same character encoding as expected by a future consumer. Case aside, it looks like you are writing the UTF-8 encoding of `á`(\xc3 \xa1) to the file, but viewing the file as if it were ISO-8859-encoded (since `\xc3` corresponds to `Ã` and `\xa1` to `¡`).

Comment: In other words, the problem may not be with the code that writes the file, but with the way you look at the file afterwards.

Answer (score -4):

How about you replace the values before, like this:

```
string.replace("á", "a").replace("é", "e").replace("í", "i").replace("ó", "o").replace("ú", "u")
```

this way you can solve the error before it happends

Comment: This is just as likely to introduce a problem as resolve one; why assume that `a` is an acceptable replacement for `á`?

Comment: In addition to what chepner said, this is also a bad way to replace a bunch of characters. The better way is with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20maketrans#str.maketrans) then `str.translate`.